# Turn on Assert by default

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I make sure Assert is On by default? I added `On[Assert]` to `init.m` but that line gets removed.

Comment: I just checked and it does work for me - I put `On[Assert]` into the `init.m` which is in the `$UserBaseDirectory` (Kernel). Are you sure your `init.m` gets loaded?

Comment: I didn't have init.m in $UserBaseDirectory, so I was modifying init.m in $UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd, maybe that's the problem

Comment: I see. The one you mentioned seems to be reconstructed programmatically every time Mathematica starts (at least, that seems to be the default behavior). For the one located in $UserBaseDirectory\Kernel, this is apparently different, so it works then.

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do is to add `Assert[On]` to `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`. Do not add it to  `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m`, this will cause an error on start-up (something like "Unknown packet On") and permanently erase your front-end settings.